# Why does my print function print nothing?

Tags: c++

here's some piece of code:

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// CLASS: SimpleArray
template <class T> class SimpleArray {

    private:

       vector<T> array;

    public:
             SimpleArray ();                             
             SimpleArray (int sz);                       
             SimpleArray (int sz, T elem);               
        void print (void);                               

};
// END OF CLASS

// CLASS CONSTRUCTORS

// Non-parameterized constructor
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray() {
    vector<T> array(0);
}

// Empty array of size sz
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray(int sz) {
    vector<T> array(sz);
}

// Array of elements elem of size sz
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray(int sz, T elem) {
    vector<T> array(sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        array.push_back(elem);
}

// CLASS METHODS
template<class T> void SimpleArray<T>::print (void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    SimpleArray<int> a(20, 6);
    a.print();


    return 0;

}
```

So, this code, as I expect, should do the following:

- create an object of type `SimpleArray<int>`, in which a vector of integers is created; In my case its a vector of 20 elements each of which is 6
- print 6 6 6 ... 6 (20 times)

What I have in fact is nothing. It does compile but it doesn't print anything and I don't understand why.

Please, help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Short answer though: your local variables called `array` are shadowing the member variable of the same name - your compiler should be warning you about this (assuming you have warnings enabled ?).

Answer (score 2):

Your constructors don't do what you think they do. You're declaring a *local variable `array`* in each of them, which hides the data member `array`. Of course, all modifications to that local variable are gone when the constructor exits, and no operations were carried out on the `array` member in the first place.

To initialise a class member, use the constructor's mem-initializer-list:

```
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray() //nothing needed here
{}

template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray(int sz) : array(sz)
{}

// Array of elements elem of size sz
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray(int sz, T elem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        array.push_back(elem);
}
```

Note that in your third constructor, you first initialised the (local variable) `array` to size `sz`, and then pushed an extra `sz` elements into it. You'd end up with a vector of size `2 * sz`, where the first `sz` elements would be default-constructed, and the second `sz` elements would be copies of `elem`. I assume that is not what you wanted, so I left out the initialisation to non-zero size in the third constructor above.

Additionally, note that `std::vector` has a constructor which will do the same thing as your third constructor, but more efficiently:

```
// Array of elements elem of size sz
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray(int sz, T elem) : array(sz, elem)
{}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
template<class T> SimpleArray<T>::SimpleArray(int sz, T elem) {
    vector<T> array(sz); // <<<<<<< new variable, not a class member!
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        array.push_back(elem);
}
```